# flume or kafka's equivalent to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, flume, apache-kafka

In Hadoop world, flume or kafka is used to streaming or collecting data and store them in Hadoop. I am just wondering that does Mango DB has some similar mechanisms or tools to achieve the some?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB is just the database layer, not the complete solution like the Hadoop ecosystem. I actually use Kafka along with Storm to store data in MongoDB in cases where there is a very large flow of incoming data which needs to be processed and stored.

Answer (score 2):

Although Flume is frequently used and treated as a member of the Hadoop ecosystem, it's not impossible to use it with other sources/sinks. MongoDB is not an exception. In fact, Flume is flexible enough to be extended to create your own custom sources/sinks. See this [project](https://github.com/leonlee/flume-ng-mongodb-sink), for example. This is a custom Flume-Mongo-sink.